# Loading a template in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am on beginner level on Backbonejs. I am trying to call simple template. But it's giving me below error:

```
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined*
```

See plnk which I have created for it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fTcL4m?p=info

**You can also find code here:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Loading a template</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Loading a template</h1>

    <div id="search_container"></div>
<script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="underscore.js@1.8.3" data-semver="1.8.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script data-require="backbone.js@1.1.2" data-semver="1.1.2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>
      SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
          this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
          var template = _.template($("#search_template").html(), {});
          this.el.html(template);
        }
      });
      var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="search_template">
      <label>Search</label>
      <input type="text" id="search_input" />
      <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: That plunkr doesn't work becuase the `url`s are like `scripts/underscore-min.js`...? Did you check whether it reproduces the issue in question..?

Comment: so do I have to test it with localhost ?

Comment: You should use cdn links for the libraries so that others can run that plunk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major issue is the order of your script tags,

```
<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
  <label>Search</label>
  <input type="text" id="search_input" />
  <input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>
```

does not exist when your script runs. You should make sure it does, By adding it before the one containing code, or wrapping your code in `$(function(){})` etc.

Another issue is that you should use `this.$el.html(template);` instead of `this.el.html(template);`

Comment: `var template = _.template($("#search_template").html(), {});` also doesn't do what he thinks it does with that version of Underscore. As of 1.7.0, `template` will be a function, not an HTML string.

Comment: @muistooshort  `html()` accepts a function that returns html string, so it'll invoke the template function and load the html. I think the difference is that `{}` here is considered as options, not data for the template function... Hopefully he'll figure that out when he tries to pass actual data :P

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, 
`render: function(){
          var variables = {search_label: "Search Label Here"};
          var template = _.template($("#search_template").html());
          this.$el.html(template(variables));
        }`

Corrected my mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: The `_.template(x,y)` behavior changed in Underscore 1.7.0 and there are a lot of old out-of-date tutorials still kicking around, that's why I mentioned the *next* bug.